# ExamplesTest driver config / start failed: webdriver session create status 500 (karate with appium)

Tags: appium, karate

```
 Scenario: launch chrome in appium
 * configure driver = 
 """
 { 
     type: 'android', 
     webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", 
     start: true, 
     httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }
 }
 """
 * def desiredConfig = 
 """
 {
    "newCommandTimeout" : 300,
    "platformVersion" : "9.0",
    "platformName" : "Android",
    "connectHardwareKeyboard" : true,
    "deviceName" : "emulator-5554",
    "avd" : "Pixel2",
    "automationName" : "UiAutomator2",
    "browserName" : "Chrome"
  }
 """
 * driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
 * driver 'http://google.com'
 * driver.input("//input[@name='q']", 'karate dsl')
```

I have done UI web testing with karate, Django. But facing issue when try to test the mobile app.

I installed:-

- android studio
- node js
- npm
- appium-doctor

Error message when running sample test:-
`ExamplesTest driver config / start failed: webdriver session create status 500, {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details"},"sessionId":null}, options: {type=android, webDriverPath=/wd/hub, start=true, httpConfig={readTimeout=120000}, target=null, webDriverSession={desiredCapabilities={newCommandTimeout=300, platformVersion=9.0, platformName=Android, connectHardwareKeyboard=true, deviceName=emulator-5554, avd=Pixel2, automationName=UiAutomator2, browserName=Chrome}}} classpath:test/test_features/android/android.feature:59`
need help to solve this. Can someone help

Comment: Have you tried running `appium-doctor` from your command line to see if it gave you steps ?

Comment: @Babu Sekaran,Yes. I cleared all the warnings that appium-doctor gave. Now, it throws the error message ** ExamplesTest driver config / start failed: webdriver session create status 500, {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Avd 'Pixel2_PIE' is not available. Please select your avd name from one of these: 'Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64'"},......**

Comment: Figured out by installing the AVD in android studio. When run karate test, it will open Emulator, but it seems very very slow and always pop-up with the App isn't responding. How can I run tests like as in android that is mentioned in this https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/743